# Following Sibling not working in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The part that I want to **scrape** is something like this:

```
<dl class="some class">
    <dt> <strong>Text1</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result1</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text2</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result2</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text3</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result3</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text4</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result4</dd>
    .  .  .
```

What I am doing currently is:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Text3')]")
```

When I do `print(e.text)` it succesfully prints the `Text3`. What I want is `Result3`. When I do this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Text3')]/following-sibling::dd")
```

This shows an error with `NoSuchElementException`. I want the Result which is next to a particular text.

I have also tried this:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("some class"):
    print(i.find_element_by_xpath("./dt[.='Text3']/following-sibling::dd").text)
```

still shows `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text `Text3` is not in the `<dt>` tag but in its child `<strong>` tag. `element.text` gives you the correct text because `element.text` returns all the text in the element and its decedents, but it's not good enough for `xpath`.

You need to get `<dt>` which has a child element with text `Text3`. Note that `following-sibling` returns all the following siblings, so you need to use index 1 to point to the first sibling

```
//dt[strong[contains(text(), 'Text3')]]/following-sibling::dd[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to get country name.

```
parent=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("dl.BuyingOptions-labeledValues")
country=parent.find_element_by_xpath("./dt[contains(.,'Country Of Origin')]/following::dd[1]")
print(country.text)
```

OR

```
country=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dl[contains(@class,'BuyingOptions-labeledValues')]//dt[contains(.,'Country Of Origin')]/following::dd[1]")
print(country.text)
```

Print:

```
Switzerland
```

Comment: Its still not working. Giving the same `NoSuchElementException`. If I print i.text it successfully prints all the table elements. If I do this:

    print(i.find_element_by_xpath("./dt[contains(.,'Text3')]").text)

It still shows same error

Comment: is your `some class` is two different class name or only one class?

Comment: One class name. The actual classes looks like this:
`<dl class = "BuyingOptions-labeledValues BuyingOptions-labeledValues--aligned BuyingOptions-labeledValues--indented u-tablet-up-showFlex"> ...</dl>`

I am just using the first one "BuyingOptions-labeledValues" in find element by class name

Comment: I can give u the link of original site as well if that will help you

Comment: Can you send link?

Comment: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/031-8919-002-ms/itt-corporation

Now I want the Country Of Origin from the table

Comment: Great!!! Can you accept that answer if it resolve your problem.By clicking on hollow under down vote button.Thanks.

Comment: When working with Selenium I typically import a Selector from scrapy import Selector. Now you can chain css and xpath selectors together.  from your dt element you could do something like this response.css('dtelement').xpath('../dd')

Answer (score 0):

I went through all comment either they are recommending the indexing or the direct text in their locator. 
Using text in locator is not actually a good idea as it won't give you expected and actual text present in an element in case of any failure. 
So always try to store values in the key-pair node of all the child node and then access the required one.

```
 List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.cssLocator(".some.class *"))
 Map<String,String> dlItems = new HashMap<String,String>();
for(int i=0;i<=el.length()/2+1;i+2){
    dlItems.put(el.get(i).getText(),el.get(i+1).getText());
}
```

the loop condition depends on the requirement.